# Opening tor.exe with specific torrc file with Python Windows11

Tags: python, tor

I'm trying to open tor.exe with a specific torrc file but its not working.I couldn't find anything on Google about it so I'm asking you.
With the following code tor.exe is not running. Can you tell my why?

```
import os
os.system(
    "Start C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor.exe /f C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/torrc"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in-mind that you're running this program threw cmd.
Change directory by
`os.system('cd C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Tor/Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/')`

Then execute tor.exe by `os.system('start tor')`

Comment: i have no problem to open the tor.exe without the torrc file.
but i want to know how to open the tor.exe with a specific torrc file